# how to check each element in an array for a specific condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have six integers stored in an array:

`[2,3,4,5,6,7]`

I would like to use each item in the array to check against a range of other integers `100 - 999` (i.e. all three-digit numbers) to find a number that has a remainder of `1` when divided by **all** the items in the array **individually**.

I'm not sure what javascript method to use for this. I'm trying a `for` loop:

```
function hasRemainder() {
  let arr = [2,3,4,5,6,7];
  for (i = 100; i < 999; i++) {
    if (i % arr[0] == 1) {
    return i;
    }
  }
}
```

but it has several problems I need to solve.

- Instead of referring to a particular item e.g. `arr[0]`, I need to find a        way to loop through all the items in the array.
- Currently, this function only returns one number (the loop stops at the first number with a remainder), but I need all the possible values in the given range.

If anyone could help with these two problems, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could map an array of values and then filter the array by checking every remainder value with one.

```js
function hasRemainder() {
    var array = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    return Array
        .from({ length: 900 }, (_, i) => i + 100)
        .filter(a => array.every(b => a % b === 1));
}

console.log(hasRemainder())
```

Comment: great, thank you. i'll have to read up on MDN about Array.from now to understand what's happening here!

Answer (score 0):

This works also;

```
function hasRemainder() {
  const arr = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
  const remainders = []
  for (i = 100; i < 999; i++) {
     const isRemainder = arr.every(numb => i % numb === 1)
     if (isRemainder) {
        remainders.push(i)
     }
    }
    return remainders
  }
```